# Action dictionary to expect type of it's key

Tags: c#, generics, types, callback, type-hinting

For now, I have an abstract class with property of this signature:

```
protected virtual IDictionary<Type, Action<object>> InitializationMap
{
    get
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Once extended, I override it, for example, like this:

```
protected override IDictionary<Type, Action<object>> InitializationMap
{
    get
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>
        {
            { typeof(INewSchoolWizardExtension), o => ((INewSchoolWizardExtension)o).InitializeWizard(this) },
            { typeof(INewSchoolProcessExtension), o => ((INewSchoolProcessExtension)o).Start() }
        };
    }
}
```

While it works, I really dislike the casting part, it really bloats the code.

What I am trying to do here, is - define an initialization map for types. So to speak, once they are resolved later on, I'd check the type of what's being resolved and call the initializer.

I was thinking to do this with generics, but didn't manage to get anywhere.

How could I implement behavior, so that the `Action` would always expect the type of it's key?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - your property is `virtual` with what seems like no meaningful implementation. Why not make it `abstract` instead?

Comment: @decPL, because abstract is obligatory, not all classes will need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This introduces a slight overhead, but is otherwise functional:

```
public class MyInitalizationDictionary : Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>
{
   public void Add<T>(Action<T> action)
   {
      this.Add(typeof(T), o => action((T)o)); //said overhead
   }
}
```

sample initializer:

```
protected override IDictionary<Type, Action<object>> InitializationMap
{
   get
   {
      return new MyInitalizationDictionary
      {
         (INewSchoolWizardExtension o) => o.InitializeWizard(this),
         (INewSchoolWizardExtension o) => o.Start()
      };
   }
}
```

Comment: Damnit decPL, other than the class name this is word-for-word what I was about to write up :p

Comment: Yes, I went to the [Leonard of Quirm](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/index.php/Going-Under-The-Water-Safely_Device)'s school of naming things :)

Answer (score 2):

Have all of the types implement an interface that initializes the type, and require all of the objects in the actions in this dictionary to implement that interface.